# How do I connect to DB2 from a docker container using ASP.Net Core?

Tags: docker, .net-core, db2, dockerfile, asp.net-core-webapi

I am attempting to connect to a DB2 server (on prem) from a Windows based Docker container.  It is currently using the IMB.Data.DB2.Core nuget package (latest).  The docker file is just the auto-generated file that Visual Studio 2019 creates with no changes.

The project is set to 64-bit and there are no errors or warnings on build.

I have searched everywhere for how to make this work and have been unable to find this problem elsewhere.  I suspect that the issue is due to my lack of Docker knowledge and DB2 needing something particular setup within the container.  I have verified that the files are being copied (locally at least) when building so they should be there.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-nanoserver-1809 AS base  
WORKDIR /app  
EXPOSE 80  
EXPOSE 443  

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-nanoserver-1809 AS build  
WORKDIR /src  
COPY ["DockerDb2Test.csproj", ""]  
RUN dotnet restore "DockerDb2Test.csproj"  
COPY . .  
WORKDIR "/src/"  
RUN dotnet build "DockerDb2Test.csproj" -c Release -o /app  

FROM build AS publish  
RUN dotnet publish "DockerDb2Test.csproj" -c Release -o /app  

FROM base AS final  
WORKDIR /app  
COPY --from=publish /app .  
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerDb2Test.dll"]
```

There's a default values controller that always works however when calling any code that attempts to access DB2, the following exception method is returned:

> Unable to load DLL 'db2app64.dll' or one of its dependencies: The
>   specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by adding the following to the Dockerfile above the ENTRYPOINT:

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/app/clidriver/lib/"
Env PATH=$PATH:"/app/clidriver/bin:/app/clidriver/lib"
RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y libxml2-dev;

Please note that I switched to a Linux container: sdk:2.2.300-stretch

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the post [.Net Core Linux - Docker - Local debugging with DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64828258/net-core-linux-docker-local-debugging-with-db2/67473299#67473299)

I have included the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable to be added as a solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Need to install one of the IBM Data Server Client Packages that ship IBM.Data.DB2.dll and other DB2 .NET assemblies/resources/managed and unmanaged dependencies.

The recommended thin client is IBM Data Server Driver Package, 10.5 Fixpack 5 link for the latest IBM Data Server Client Packages is:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24038920

Comment: What? That release of 10.5 is 5 years old! There are far newer versions of the client than that, and it's not even the newest version of 10.5... [This link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27007053) always lists the available versions for download.  Also, that would be the version for the full .NET framework. He needs the one for .NET Core, which is different. See [this link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/96960515-2ea1-4391-8170-b0515d08e4da/entry/DB2DotnetCore?lang=en) for more info.