# .Net Core Linux - Docker - Local debugging with DB2

Tags: linux, docker, debugging, db2, .net-core-3.1

.Net Core (3.1) Web API using Docker (Linux container).

I have a Db2 connection via nuget package IBM.Data.DB2.Core-lnx (3.1.0.300).

This Db2 connection works fine when I build and run my Dockerfile independently of VisualStudio 2019.

However, when attempting to debug via VS (fast mode), I run into this exception:

> Unable to load shared library 'libdb2.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibdb2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

My guess is this failure to locate resources is because of the way fast mode debugging works with Docker containers. With the app output copied to a mount, my IBM ENV variables aren't able to find the NuGet clidriver folder. These typically look like this:

```
ENV DB2_CLI_DRIVER_INSTALL_PATH="/app/clidriver" \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/app/clidriver/lib" \
    LIBPATH="/app/clidriver/lib" \
    PATH=$PATH:"/app/clidriver/bin:/app/clidriver/lib:/app/clidriver/adm"
```

How can I update these to point to the mounted app contents? Assuming that is the problem...

*Note that I am installing package libxml2-dev in the base of my Dockerfile.

If anyone has a successful strategy for debugging Db2 connections in a Linux container, I would love to hear what you've done. Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a shell on the debugging container allowed me to see the mounted contents and get the clidriver path. Setting this in the Db2 environment variables fixed the issue:

```
ENV DB2_CLI_DRIVER_INSTALL_PATH="/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/clidriver" \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/clidriver/lib" \
    LIBPATH="/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/clidriver/lib" \
    PATH=$PATH:"/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/clidriver/bin:/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/clidriver/lib:/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/clidriver/adm"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing these concerns almost for a week, glad could resolve the issue.

Solution:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<app release folder path>/netcoreapp3.1/clidriver/lib
```

when you include the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable, the PATH value gets appended to the existing values along with "../root/usr/lib64"

Please note, If you don't include the LD_LIBRARY_PATH the pod will error out.

Comment: Hi Vishwajeet, for clarity you might want to move your comment into your answer.