# Unable to load shared library 'libdb2.so'

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-5.0, ibm-data-db2

We are working on deploying asp .net core api in google cloud run serverless container, as our api has dependency with **db2 drivers** so we have made following changes in dockerfile, and to download DB2 Drivers Package we are using this version of nuget package reference - "Net5.IBM.Data.Db2-lnx" Version="5.0.0.500", but our API is throwing below mentioned error.

Unable to load shared library 'libdb2.so' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibdb2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Following is our docker file changes.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install jq dos2unix curl -y

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

RUN chmod -R 777 /app
ENV DB2_CLI_DRIVER_INSTALL_PATH=/app/clidriver
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/app/clidriver/lib
ENV LIBPATH=/app/clidriver/lib
ENV PATH=$PATH:/app/clidriver/bin:/app/clidriver/lib

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SourceCode/SomeAPI.WebApi/SomeAPI.WebApi.csproj", "SourceCode/SomeAPI.WebApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SourceCode/SomeAPI.WebApi/SomeAPI.WebApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SourceCode/SomeAPI.WebApi"
RUN dotnet build "SomeAPI.WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SomeAPI.WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SomeAPI.WebApi.dll"]
```

Comment: [.Net Core Linux - Docker - Local debugging with DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64828258/net-core-linux-docker-local-debugging-with-db2) suggests the library might be in a different path; have you tried looking in the partially-built image to see if it exists, but somewhere other than `/app/clidriver`?

Comment: thanks for replying, Yes i already checked that running same image in my local, clidriver is only in 1 path
i.e. /app/clidriver

Comment: Below command i run to find clidriver path
PS C:\WINDOWS> docker exec -it 81c1b8219edc bash
root@81c1b8219edc:/app# cd ..
root@81c1b8219edc:/# find / -name clidriver
/app/clidriver

also i checked above link earlier as well that is for netcoreapp3.1 and we are using net5.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer served me really well.

The only thing I changed besides this was:

1. Instaling the Net5.IBM.Data.Db2-lnx NuGet package
   [Link to NuGET page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Net5.IBM.Data.Db2-lnx)
2. Changing the aspnet runtime to Debian
   mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0.15-bullseye-slim-amd64

**EDIT:** You have to remove "IBM.EntityFrameworkCore" from your projects, and only include "IBM.EntityFrameworkCore-lnx". This will for for sure hinder your dev process, unless you manage to find a workaround for running IBM.EntityFrameworkCore locally on Windows. Hope this helps.